# Android application closing upon entering values into database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, numberformatexception

I have a fully functioning application that accepts user input and saves it to a database. Upon clicking on a "log" button, the information is displayed in a listview. I created a for loop that keeps a running total of one of my columns. The column name is "grandTotal", which is a running total of tips that I have made for the night. Everything was working great until I accidentally clicked the save button without inputting anything, and now it crashed, and I can't figure out how to find a way around it. Any help would be appreciated! My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry, null);

    TextView name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    TextView contact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
    TextView address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressConverted);
    TextView orderTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderTotalConverted);
    TextView amountReceived = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountReceivedConverted);
    TextView tip = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipConverted);
    TextView mileage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mileageConverted);
    TextView grandTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grandTotalConverted);
    Button delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    PhoneBook list = contactList.get(position);

    name.setText(list.getName());
    contact.setText(list.getPhoneNumber());
    address.setText(list.getAddress());
    orderTotal.setText(list.getOrderTotal());
    amountReceived.setText(list.getAmountReceived());
    tip.setText(list.getTip());
    mileage.setText(list.getMileage());
    grandTotal.setText(list.getGrandTotal());
    delete.setOnClickListener(new ListItemClickListener(position, list));


    TextView deliveryNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliveryNum);
    deliveryNumber.setText("Delivery # " + (position + 1));

    TextView runningTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.runningTotal);

    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++)
    {
        sum = Float.valueOf(list.getGrandTotal()) + sum;
    }
    runningTotal.setText("Running Total: " + sum);

    return convertView;
}
```

The error I'm getting is from this line of code in my for loop:

```
sum = Float.valueOf(list.getGrandTotal()) + sum;
```

Like I said, the app was running great as long as I was actually saving data to the database, but when I saved (nothing), it ended up crashing and hasn't run since.

The logcat error I'm getting is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.boley.databaseexample, PID: 23988
                                                                               java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
                                                                                   at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                   at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:343)
                                                                                   at com.example.boley.databaseexample.PhonebookAdapter.getView(PhonebookAdapter.java:86)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1111)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:631)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1891)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1487)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7467)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Maybe I'll have to find out where my database is being saved and delete the entry that I accidentally saved and delete it. And from now on, just make sure I'm actually saving values, but if there is a way to fix it I would definitely appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Please read an exception...  It's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I saved (nothing), it ended up crashing

so i think your `list.getGrandTotal()` doesn't have any value or has empty string and it causes the `NumberFormatException`

so check before parsing into Float:

```
String value = list.getGrandTotal();
if (value != null && value.length() > 0) {
    sum = Float.valueOf(value) + sum;
    }
```

Comment: When I input the above code into my for loop, for some reason the totals aren't computed correctly. I tried putting 3 entries into my database with totals of 8.75, 9.06, and 3.75. And the outcome for the running totals for each one was 8.75, 18.12, and 11.25. It seems the values are being multiplied by the position number in the database.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, the values weren't computing correctly with the way I had it in the first place. I just put 5.00 for all 3 totals the first time, and with it displaying 15.00, I thought it was correct. But really, the 3rd entry was just multiplying the 5.00 by 3. I tried putting String value = list.getGrandTotal(); outside my for loop as well with no luck.

Comment: i think it's because of the `getview(position)`....it is not best practice..to add this code in `getview()` casue `getview()` called in each time the view gets created in list..you can not control it..also if your question crash solved you should mark the answer...thankx

Comment: I got it to work by doing sum = Float.valueOf(contactList.get(I).getGrandTotal()) + sum; Is it bad practice if it is working by putting it inside the getview? I will accept your answer.

Comment: did it work in every cases...? like when you scroll  the view..if it's ok ..i think you can add it in `getView()`..